# How to enable Bower in VS 2017 for Mac?

Tags: javascript, dependencies, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-mac

I'm learning to use Visual Studio 2017 for Mac to develop ASP.NET Core MVC apps with it. So far so good, but my problem is that I don't know how to handle/manage JavaScript libraries. Supposedly you have to use Bower (the 4 default dependencies in every new project have a .bower.json file in their respective folders), but there's no bower.json file on the project and honestly I don't know where to start.

I assume I should start by installing Bower in my development machine, but how do I integrate it with a build action in VS? I'm assuming that in a proper build, Bower should download and install all my JS dependencies.

I've searched for answers but most search results say that Bower is deprecated and I should be using LibMan and there are no tutorials about using LibMan on macOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after trying tip after tip, I finally found a solution. Posting here in case someone else has the same problem.

Two things:

- The solution uses Libman instead of Bower.
- I presume you already have VS for Mac and the .NET Core SDK installed and already created a solution with an ASP.NET Core MVC project inside.

Do the following:

1. Install Libman with the following command in Terminal: `dotnet tool install -g Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Cli`
2. Remove all folders under the `lib/` folder in your project. You'll have Libman manage all your JS dependencies.
3. Add a JSON file to your project. Call it `libman.json`.
4. Add the following content to `libman.json` and save it:

   ```
   {
       "version": "1.0",
       "defaultProvider": "cdnjs",
       "libraries": [
           {
               "library": "twitter-bootstrap@3.3.7",
               "destination": "wwwroot/lib/bootstrap"
           },
           {
               "library": "jquery@1.12.4",
               "destination": "wwwroot/lib/jquery"
           },
           {
               "library": "jquery-validate@1.17.0",
               "destination": "wwwroot/lib/jquery-validation"
           },
           {
               "library": "jquery-validation-unobtrusive@3.2.9",
               "destination": "wwwroot/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive"
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
5. Go to **Project** > **[PROJECT_NAME] Options...** and there, in **Build** > **Custom commands**, add a *Before build* command. The command is `/Users/[YOUR_USERNAME]/.dotnet/tools/libman restore` and in the Working directory field, use the macro `${ProjectDir}`. Save the changes.

Now, every time you compile the solution (or the specific project), Libman will fetch and install the libraries noted in `libman.json`. If the files are in their destinations already, Libman does not do anything. If a previous Libman execution downloaded the libraries, then it retrieves them from its internal cache.

Hope this helps.

Comment: do you normally exclude `/wwwroot/lib/*` from git?